# What is the root cause of save! returning true, but the record not actually being saved? Can callbacks produce this behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a test suite which tests the behavior of a Rails Model, and I added in some callbacks to the model to test for changes in one of the attributes.  These tests worked fine before I added the callbacks (which do nothing but print attribute values to the console).  After I add the callbacks, the object.save! method which I call no longer works.  In the context of the method that calls save!, the record is apparently updated and the object is saved.  But when I find that record after completion of the method, the object is unchanged.  No error is thrown by save! so its a bit puzzling:

There are two objects I am testing, a "Branch" object which implements an ordered list of "ApprovalNodes" comprising the branch.  The branch calls save on its constituent nodes when a new node is added to the branch.  However, notwithstanding the save method, one of the nodes which is changed is not saved when the callbacks are present.

Node Code:

```
class ApprovalNode < ApplicationRecord
  before_update :before_update_handler
  after_update :after_update_handler
  around_update :around_update_handler
  belongs_to :branch, optional: true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :approval
  enum decision: { not_started: -1, pending: 0, approved: 1, declined: 2, abstained: 3, cut_off: 4 }

  def decided?
    return false if self.pending?
    return true
  end

  private
  def handler(phase)
       puts phase.capitalize
       puts "decision value: #{self.decision}"
       puts "changes: #{self.changes}"
       puts "will save_change: #{self.will_save_change_to_attribute?(:decision)}"
       puts "changed attributes: #{self.changed_attributes}"
  end
  def before_update_handler
    handler("before update") if self.will_save_change_to_attribute?(:decision)
    true
  end
  def after_update_handler
    handler("after Update") if self.will_save_change_to_attribute?(:decision)
    true
  end

  def around_update_handler
    handler("around update") if self.will_save_change_to_attribute?(:decision)
    true
  end

  end
```

Branch Code:

```
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :approval
  has_many :approval_nodes

  # param [ApprovalNode] node
  def append_node(node)
    old_last_node = nil
    if node.branch_id != self.id
      raise "Branch Id must match node.branch_id"
    end

    if self.node_count == 0
      self.first_node_id = node.id
      self.last_node_id = node.id
      node.next_node_id = nil
      node.prev_node_id = nil

    else
      old_last_node = ApprovalNode.find(self.last_node_id)
      # ! this change does not get persisted when save! is called
      # when handlers are present in ApprovalNode code.
      # When handlers are removed, this works as expected.
      old_last_node.next_node_id = node.id    
      old_last_node.save!
      node.prev_node_id = old_last_node.id
      self.last_node_id = node.id
    end
      node.save!
      self.node_count += 1
      self.save!
    return node
  end
end
```

Failing RSpec test (succeeds when callbacks are removed).

```
 it 'keeps track of next and last nodes properly' do
    wf= NodeWorkflow.new(branch)
    node1 = wf.append_node(user1.id)
    expect(node1.next_node_id).to be_nil
    expect(node1.prev_node_id).to be_nil

    node2 = wf.append_node(user2.id)
    node1.reload
    expect(node1.next_node_id).to eq(node2.id)  #FAILS HERE node1.next_node_id is nil
    expect(node1.prev_node_id).to be_nil
    expect(node2.next_node_id).to be_nil
    expect(node2.prev_node_id).to eq(node1.id)

  end
```

Helper methods called by test in NodeWorkflow:

```
class NodeWorkflow

  def append_node(user_id)
    # @type [ApprovalNode] node
    node = _create_node(user_id)
    node.save!
    node = @branch.append_node(node)
    node
  end

   # @param [Branch] branch
  def initialize(branch)
    @branch = branch
  end


  private

  def _create_node(user_id)
    node = ApprovalNode.new
    node.branch_id = @branch.id
    node.approval_id = @branch.approval_id
    node.user_id = user_id
    return node
  end
end
```

Comment: Executive summary: Your `around_update` callback doesn't `yield` so the update never happens. To be fair, the documentation isn't exactly easy to find or all that clear.

Comment: That's interesting.  I knew that yield was involved somehow, but I thought it was the save action yielded to whatever method you defined in around not the other way round.  It's odd that save! doesn't result in an error of some kind if failure to .yield prevents saving from happening.  I don't think it is strictly a duplicate because the problem I was having was "not saving", and the subject of the thread referenced is "how do around callbacks work".

Comment: But the answer to your problem is, more or less, "that's not how `around_update` works" so I think they're both really the same thing. The `yield` part is what sends an UPDATE to the database but AR doesn't have any way of knowing that you're not `yield`ing, it could but that would add some accounting busywork that presumably is considered pointless. The documentation for `around_update` is garbage (if you can even find it), it helps if you already know the answer.

Comment: I reallyh appreciate the pointer to the answer, but because two questions have the same answer, that doesn't make them the same question.  In my case, my question was "why is it that my object is not saving when I call save! and no error is reported" I have used before callbacks and after callbacks before where yield is not required, and it did not occur to me that maybe around callbacks have the capacity to kill a save if you don't type the magic word.  Other users facing the same circumstance might not find the answer you've referred facing a similarly mysterious failure to save.